# Upload, edit and replace the existing file image in html and angular 4

Tags: html, angular

I am quite new to Angular. My exact problem statement is - 
I want to show a default image. If i click on the image, File selector window should open. When i select an image, i should be able to see and edit the image and finally this image should override the default image and also send this image to an API and display existing profile image if any. I want to do all this using HTML and Angular 4. 
Please point me to any link if a solution to this problem already exists.

I have just been able to open the file selector till now by doing this -

```
<div>
            <ion-input type="file" style="display: none" ngModel (change)="getFiles($event)"></ion-input>
            <img src="assets/imgs/uploadImage.png" class="form-control" style="width : 20% ; height : 15%" (click)="selectFile()">
        </div>
```

and

```
 selectFile(): void {
    let element: HTMLElement = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]') as HTMLElement;
    element.click();
  }

  public async getFiles(event) {
    console.log(event.target.files);
  }
```

Comment: Versions above 2+ called as Angular alone and not Angular Js.. So you are using Angular 4 and not Angular Js.. And as per your question please post the code that you have tried to achieve the result and explain in what stage you are stucked with..

Answer (score 0):

To show the profile image again, it's depend on how is the api server store your image? what is the format in that api server send an image to you, binary, cloud url...?
But for choose file and send it to server you can take a look this post...
https://www.academind.com/learn/angular/snippets/angular-image-upload-made-easy/

Comment: Sending the image to server and loading the image from API is not my main problem. My main concern is to show a default image, preview and crop it and then display it as profile picture.

Comment: Yes, maybe Alyle UI is what you are looking for...
https://alyle-ui.firebaseapp.com/components/resizing-cropping-images